# Adding Java Applet help HTML (on Forumotion.com)

Tags: java, html, applet

I am running a game server and I have the .jar file which works fine and runs perfectly. I'm trying to embed it into an HTML page on my forumotion website (it's a forum maker, but you can add HTML pages)

I originally tried doing

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>YOUR CLIENT TITLE</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {heiht:100%;margin:0 padding:0;}
#page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%}
#content {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-background"><img src="ADD YOUR BACKGROUND IMG HERE"   width="100%" height="100%" alt"The greatest server ever"></div>
<div id="content">
<center><applet code="client.class" archive="client.jar" width="760px" height="506px">
Java is not installed on your machine or your browser does not allowed Java  Applet to run<br /><br />Get the latest Java technology at <a href="http://www.java.com/">http://www.java.com/</a>
</applet></center>
<center></center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But that wouldn't work. The client.jar is uploaded to the public folder in drop box so when that link is reached it downloads automatically. But the client isn't running.

I then tried doing  or whatever, but I'm not very good at html. Here was my shot for that.

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
<param name="code" value="client.class" />
<param name="archive"     value="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83349258/client.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

Any tips?

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).